# How to use if($wp_query->query_vars['name'] == 'pagethatdontexist') without getting a 404? How to suppress 404

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, 404-error

i want to do something if my url is /pagethatdontexist
But I dont want wp sending 404 headers.  I tried this:

```
add_action('wp', array($this,'awp'));   
function awp(){
global $wp_query ;
debug($wp_query->is_404);
if($wp_query->query_vars['name'] == 'pagethatdontexist')
    debug('yes were at pagethatdontexist');;
$wp_query->is_404 = false;
debug($wp_query->is_404);
}
```

Which works, but still, 404 headers are sent.

Where can I hook in and tell wp not to send the 404?

EDIT -- well, this seems to do the trick, I'm not sure if it's Kosher.

```
function filter_status_header(  $status_header, $header, $text, $protocol ){
    global $wp_query;
    if (iDontWant404()){
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;// still sends 404 unless:
        return 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK';  
    }
    else
        return $status_header;
}
add_filter('status_header',array($this,'filter_status_header'),4,4);
```

Comment: What do you want to do instead of going to the 404 page?

Comment: Wul, whatever I want.  I'll figure sth out from there.  First I've got to get it to not 404 if we are on a url that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an earlier action, [`request`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request), to do whatever you need. It allows you to modify query variables, or even cancel the entire request without issuing a 404 error:

```
function wpse112929_cancel_request_parsing( $query_vars ) {
    if ( in_array( 'pagethatdontexist', $query_vars ) ) {
        return array();
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
add_action( 'request', 'wpse112929_cancel_request_parsing' );
```

I used `in_array()` here instead of a direct comparison, because
the actual match
depends on your permalink structure.
It would be `name` for `/%postname%/`, `category_name` for `/%category%/%postname%/`, `pagename` for `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`, etc.

You can also check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As someone (somewhere) said it's not a good idea to fall into a 404 without sending headers. The right way to do things is to redirect somewhere else.

If you fall into the 404 template, you'll have the 404 headers sent as logic as is. Search engines will also love you!

Cheers.